# Стою один. Часть речи

Tags: морфология

> Стою один среди равнины голой...
>   *Есенин*

Какой частью речи будет являться слово *один*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я призываю к более аккуратным формулировкам.

Даже если трактовать "один" как "одинокий" (что не очевидно, сравните: стоим вдвоем), то **один** тут всего лишь **числительное, использованное как прилагательное**..Или - "...**в значении прилагательного**"

Именно так дается и Вики (на которую ссылается Aer) и у Кузнецова.
При этом в списке частей речи для слова "один" значится лишь числительное и местоимение (ещё "местоименное прилагательное" - это отдельный случай, не наш точно).

Разница в формулировках ***"является [прилагательным]"*** и ***"используется как [прилагательное]"*** довольно существенная. Чтобы слово прошло процесс адъективации, необходимо, чтобы оно приобрело значение, существенно отличное от исходного, а не просто использовалась в синтаксической роли прилагательного. У нас со словом "один" этого не происходит, в любой роли оно сохраняет семантику числительного.

Поэтому я настаиваю именно на вышеприведенной формулировке.

**Один - числительное, использованное как прилагательное**. А не просто "прилагательное".

Comment: Я сделал оговорку сразу же после "является прилагательным". Вы правы, однако моей целью было дать ответ, который будет простым и верным для школы или какой-нибудь олимпиады. Также обратите внимание, что позже я пишу: "употреблено в значении прилагательного". Тем не менее под вашим давлением я изменю формулировку, иначе создается ощущение, что моя цель — путать авторов вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

В данном предложении слово «один» выполняет функцию **прилагательного**, значащего «без других, в отдельности от других, в одиночестве». Вспомните известные лермонтовские строки: «Выхожу *один* я на дорогу» — где «один» также употреблено в значении прилагательного.

https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD

Comment: А это не может быть числительным?

Comment: @Alena нет, не может.

Comment: Спасибо большое!)