# Разбор предложения "Остался совсем один"

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

В предложении

> Остался совсем **один**

к какой части речи относится и каким членом предложения является слово *один*?

По смыслу и исходя из синтаксиса очень напоминает краткое прилагательное. Помогите разобраться.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Стою один. Часть речи](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434111/%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8)

Answer (score 3):

О слове ***один***

В Грамматике-80 слово ***один*** названо счетно-местоименным словом, которое может иметь как количественное, так и другие значения.

Слово ***один*** может быть существительным, прилагательным, местоимением, частицей.

Слово ***один*** в форме И.п и В.п. имеет окончания существительных, а в остальных падежах — окончания прилагательных. Такую же систему словоизменения имеет, к примеру, притяжательное прилагательное ***мамин.***

***Остался совсем один.***

2) Часть речи: **прилагательное**

Из словаря Ефремовой [https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/один](https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD)

II прил. 1. Обособленный от других, оставшийся или существующий без других, в отдельности; отдельный. 2. **Не живущий в семье, не имеющий семьи, родственников, близких; одинокий**.

2) Член предложения

***Один*** — **именная часть составного именного сказуемого**;  остался — полузнаменательная связка.